# in powershell, is there a way to pipe an output to another script?

Tags: powershell, piping

I have a script that writes output to a log file and also the console.  I am running the command Add-WindowsFeatures...  I want to take output of this command and pipe it to my script.  Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want the output of the log file or the output of the script?

Comment: I want the output of command add-windowsfeature piping to this script, which writes to the logfile

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely.  You just need to include the CmdletBinding attribute on your param statement.  Then, add an attribute to one of your parameters which details the way the pipeline input binds to the parameter.  For instance put this in c:\temp\get-extension.ps1:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true)][System.IO.FileInfo[]]$file
)

process {
  $file.Extension
}
```

Then, you can do this:

```
dir -File| C:\temp\get-extension.ps1
```

updating to address the latest comment: I'm guessing that setting the parameter type to `[object[]]$stuff` rather than `[fileinfo[]]` and putting

```
$stuff | out-file c:\logs\logfile.txt  #or wherever you want
```

in the process block will get you close.

Comment: but when I do add-windowsfeatures| c:\....ps1, I just see microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.FeatureOperationResult in my log file.  I am not seeing output from this command

Comment: Does this work: $stuff.ToString() | out-file c:\logs\logfile.txt